# Jquery if css value not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hey guys so I'm working on a gallery, and I have the selector images being moved left and right 15vw.
I want it so when you click to the edge of the gallery it wont let you keep on scrolling past the images.

https://jsfiddle.net/9z3g7L3s/6/

**This is my code:**

```
$(".left").click(function() {
    if ($('#image-selector').css('left') == '129vw') {
        //some code here
    } else {
        $('#image-selector').animate({left: "+=15vw"});
    }
})
```

I can't get it to work, when the image-selector's left="129vw" and I click #left, it still moves over 15vw as per the else.

Comment: I think this might be a typo? `('left') == '=129vw')`

Comment: yeah that was, edited it

Comment: Could you please provide a working snippet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9z3g7L3s/6/

Answer (score 0):

The jquery css  will always give you the computed value and not what you have specified in the css file , for eg if you give '129vw' , it will give you the computed value in px , for eg: 338px. You can try this in the browser with element.

Comment: So what should I do to fix that?

Comment: find a diff way for your logic , maybe instead of checking the 'vw' you can check for a class which you can add , I'm sure what is the context of your logic , maybe if you can give more info on that ?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to show how you can handle it by using it as dom node , https://jsfiddle.net/9z3g7L3s/7/

Answer (score 0):

You should work with px values. `$('#image-selector').css('left')` gives px value, run the below snippet to see it in action:

```js
console.log($('#image-selector').css('left'))
```

```css
#image-selector {
  left:10vw;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image-selector">
  Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

---

vw's unit is cm.

1vw = %1 of viewport
viewport = size of browser window (**cm**)

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

---

The relation between cm and px depends on client's DPI. You should first get that relation.

Another thing is that you use `$('#image-selector').css('left')` in comparison which has output like this: **20px**. It's output is not a numeric value. You can use offset().left or position().left depending parent element is document or another DOM element in the document. Check these for the difference: [position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/) and [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

One last thing: using <= in comparison is better than ==

So here is the solution you can try:

```
 var windowWidth = $(window).width(); // in px
    var vwInPx = windowWidth/100; // because 1vw = %1 of viewport    
    var checkConditionOfLeftVal = 129;
    var animateVal = 15;
    $(".left").click(function() {
        if ($('#image-selector').offset().left <= checkConditionOfLeftVal*vwInPx) {
            //some code here
        } else {
            $('#image-selector').animate({left: "+=" + animateVal*vwInPx});
        }
    })
```

Here is the jsFiddle example forked from your's: https://jsfiddle.net/er_han/cx4Lr9gf/1/